# removing html div content using jquery when resizing screen/window

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery I need to remove this html code and the `{menu}` tag inside when the browser or window is resized to a smaller screen size for responsive web design.

```
<div id="menu">{menu}</div>
```

I'm new to jQuery so any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does that mean that `#menu` should come back if the screen gets large enough again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use jQuery, just add a media query to your style sheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{
    #menu { display: none; }
}
```

This way, if the screen happens to change (e.g. goes to landscape, or perhaps the browser is resized), the menu will re-appear again.

Comment: +1 this is very smooth. Nice one, I just played around with it in a [**basic fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxY9G/) and the results are nice. I don't even feel like my jQuery alternative answer is relevant and I remove it for now, unless OP can't amend CSS or has any other reservations/issues with the CSS solution.

Comment: Man I was just about to implement JQuery when I saw this thanks!